# What is an efficient way to maintain a local readonly copy of a live remote MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, cron, devops

I maintain a server that runs daily cron jobs to aggregate data sources and generate reports, accessible by a private Ruby on Rails application.

One of our data sources is a partial dump of one of our partner's databases. The partner runs an active application and the MySQL DB has hundreds of tables. They have given us read-only access to a relatively underpowered readonly slave of their application DB.

Because of latency issues and performance bottlenecking on their slave DB, we have been maintaining a limited local copy of their DB. We only need about 20 tables for our reports, so I only dump those tables. We also only need the data to a daily granularity, so realtime sync is not a requirement.

For a few months, I had implemented a nightly cron which streamed the dump  of the necessary tables into a local `production_tmp` database. Then, when all tables were imported, I dropped `production` and renamed `production_tmp` to `production`. This was working until the DB grew to over 25GB, and we started running into disk space limitations.

For now, I have removed the redundancy step and am just streaming the dump straight into `production` on our local server. This feels a bit flimsy to me, and I would like to implement a safer approach. Also, currently doing the full dump/load takes our server over 2 hours, and I'd like to implement an approach that doesn't take as long. The database will only keep growing, so I'd like to implement something future proof.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using the `hot backup` feature of mySQL?  It sounds like you're dumping the entire DB in order to do this transfer but really only the changes should be moved.    More info: [Incremental Backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_incremental_backup)

Comment: @SusannahPotts is the only way to do that with MySQL Enterprise Edition?

Comment: I believe so...MySQL is pretty strict about functionality on paid versions.  I had assumed you would be using EE version seeing as MySQL licensing doesn't allow for commercial use...at least from the bit of their license I had read.

Comment: Using GPL MySQL for commercial use is permitted as long as you don't redistribute MySQL

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @HunterBridges: You *can* redistribute MySQL for commercial or noncommercial purposes, as long as everything you distribute with it has a GPL-compatible license.

Answer (score 2):

I take it you have never heard of, or considered [MySQL Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html)?

The idea is that you do your backup & restore once, and then configure the replica to "subscribe" to a continuous stream of changes as they are made on the primary MySQL instance. Any change applied to the primary is applied automatically to the replica within seconds. You don't have to do the backup & restore procedure again, unless the replica gets damaged.

It takes some care to set up and keep working, but it's a much more efficient method of keeping two instances in sync.

---

@SusannahPotts mentions hot backup and/or incremental backup. You can get both of these features for free, without paying for MySQL Enterprise using [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup).

You can also consider using [MySQL Transportable Tablespaces](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tablespace-copying.html).

---

You'll need filesystem access to run either Percona XtraBackup or MySQL Enterprise Backup. It's not possible to use these physical backup tools for Amazon RDS, for example.

One alternative is to create a replication slave in the same network as the live system, and run Percona XtraBackup on that slave, where you do have filesystem access.

Another option is to stream the binary logs to another host (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog-backup.html) and then transfer them periodically to your local instance and replay them.

Each of these solutions has pros and cons. It's hard to recommend which solution is best for you, because you aren't sharing full details about your requirements.

Comment: No need to be condescending. I am familiar with replication, but am not sure whether it is the best choice for sync'ing off of a remote DB which is already a slave. Perhaps it also should be noted that the only access I have to the remove slave is via a MySQL-only SSH tunnel

Comment: Please don't take my answer as condescending. That's not my intention. There's nothing in your question that indicates you know about the replication option. Many people don't.

Comment: Percona XtraBackup looks like a good option to explore. Transportable Tablespaces would be good if we had filesystem access on the remote server, but we do not.

Answer (score 1):

> This was working until the DB grew to over 25GB, and we started running into disk space limitations.

Some question marks "here":

- Why don't you just increase the available Diskspace for your database? 25 GB seems nothing when it comes down to disk-space?
- Why don't you modify your script to: download table1, import table1_tmp, drop table1_prod, rename table1_tmp to table1_prod; rinse and repeat.

Other than that:

- Why don't you ask your partner for a system with enough performance to run your reports on? I'm quite sure, he would prefer this rather than having YOU download sensitive data every day to your "local site"?

Last thought (requires MySQL Enterprise Backup https://www.mysql.de/products/enterprise/backup.html):

- Rather than dumping, downloading and importing 25 GB every day:
- Create a full backup
- Download and import
- Use Differential or incremental backups from now.
- The next day you download (and import) only the data-delta: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/4.0/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html

Comment: Good recommendations. Looking at those first two points, I moved my DB to a flexible block storage volume. I also have changed my script to sync per table now, which dramatically reduces disk overhead needed for the sync. Thanks for the suggestions!